Why am I getting cocoapods error such as ignorring ffi as its extensions are not built?
When I check the cocopods pod --version, this is what I am getting.
Ignoring ffi-1.16.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.16.3
Ignoring debug-1.9.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.9.1
Ignoring racc-1.7.3 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.7.3
Ignoring rbs-3.4.0 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine rbs --version 3.4.0
1.15.2
How can I fix this, so that I dont get any cocoapods error on run?
